# Neural Network weights and biases Nan

Tags: java, python, neural-network

I know that you will get NaNs in neural network if you have too high learning rate. But I'm curious why you get NaNs with high learning rate but not in low learning rate. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning rate is used to calculate how much adjustment is made to weights. If it is more than 1, then adjustment can grow with time instead of getting smaller and smaller. To illustrate: you're 1 meter away from target; your learning rate is 3 so you step `1 * 3 = 3` meters towards it and overshoot; now you're 2 meters away from target, you step `2 * 3 = 6` meters and 4 meters away from target.... and so on.

This way you can eventually overflow weight value. Probably your particular implementation deals with that by assigning NaN to weight value instead of throwing error.